# Google Publisher Console shows destroyed ad slots + warnings

Tags: google-dfp, google-publisher-tag

We're working on implementing GPT into our SPA written in VueJS. Whenever a user navigates to a different page we call `googletag.destroySlots();` for the slots we want to remove, before the DIV element is removed from the DOM (beforeDestroyed hook in VueJS, removed the google.cmd.push())

The issue is the following error shows up in the Google Publisher Console:

`googletag.defineSlot was called more times than there are DIVs in the DOM associated with ad slots while in Single Request Mode. This will impact impression counts.`

Besides the warning the Ad Slot will still show up as overlay and in the Ad Slots section of the Console, closing and reopening the console doesn't work.

I've tried the following to reproduce it:

1. Define a slot with googletag.defineSlot
2. load in an ad using prebid then googletag.refresh (shows fine)
3. Call googletag.destroySlots()
4. Remove the DIV element that was linked to that slot
5. Started Publisher Console

In this scenario the warning appears and the Ad Slot is listed in the console.

So my question is, should we ignore this warning? Because we are properly calling destroySlots, and the slot isn't listed under getSlots(); either.

Comment: do you destroy all slots and generate adcalls for all of your defined slots ?